# dcast issue on dataframe consisting two columns

Tags: r, dcast

I have a dataframe with two columns and trying to convert it two wide format as shown below. However, I am not able to figure out for a data frame consisting only a numeric and a non numeric column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

sample_frame<-data.frame(id=c("x","x","y","y","z","z"),value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

desired_output<-cbind(x=filter(sample_frame,id=="x")$value,
                       y=filter(sample_frame,id=="y")$value,
                      z=filter(sample_frame,id=="z")$value)
sample_frame
desired_output

desired_output<-dcast(sample_frame,id~.,value.var="value")
desired_output

> sample_frame
  id value
1  x     1
2  x     2
3  y     3
4  y     4
5  z     5
6  z     6
> desired_output
     x y z
[1,] 1 3 5
[2,] 2 4 6
> 
> desired_output<-dcast(sample_frame,id~.,value.var="value")
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
> desired_output
  id .
1  x 2
2  y 2
3  z 2
```

As shown above using dcast is giving me aggregation.

Comment: @thelatemail added package information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sequence numbers within id for the left hand side.  We use 1:2 because each id spans two rows.

```
dcast(1:2 ~ id, data = sample_frame)[-1]
##   x y z
## 1 1 3 5
## 2 2 4 6
```

If you don't know how many rows each id spans or if the rows are not adjacent or if not all id's span the same number of rows use this to generate the left hand side.

```
s <- with(sample_frame, ave(value, id, FUN = seq_along))
dcast(s ~ id, data = sample_frame)[-1]
```

See the comments below for an alternative to `s` if using data.table is ok.

### Base solution

A solution using only base R is the following where `s` is from above.

```
xtabs(value ~ s + id, sample_frame)
```

giving the following xtabs object:

```
   id
s   x y z
  1 1 3 5
  2 2 4 6
```

Comment: In this case, we need to know that resultant table will have 2 rows beforehand.

Comment: We don't know that that is a problem but just in case I have added code to show how to handle it.

Comment: could you also consider: `dcast(rowid(id) ~ id, data = sample_frame)[-1]`? just wondering

Comment: @Ben, The question is using reshape2 rather than data.table but if it's acceptable to switch to data.table then that would work.

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyverse` you can create a unique row number for each `id` and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

sample_frame %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = value) %>%
   select(-row)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      x     y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3     5
#2     2     4     6
```